# AWS Boto3 EKS - how to check for cluster updates

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-eks

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/eks.html#EKS.Client.describe_update

This is a very specific question but does anyone know if there's boto3 EKS method that will show any available updates for an EKS cluster.

I've looked through the documentation I've linked above, but can't see any way to show available updates, only can see ways to see previous updates.

Comment: They don't have an API for this AFAIK. They generally publish 3-4 versions per year, so it can be generally handled as a quarterly maintenance task. There shouldn't be security issues with running the old versions until you get more than 4 behind, as they continue to maintain security for that many versions.

Answer (score 0):

A year late but I've solved this for anyone still struggling with it. It's a little grim and could probably be more efficient, but it works... It uses the describe_addon_versions method to pull the latest compatible versions for each addon into a list, then find the latest version from that list. The assumption being that at least one addon will be listed as compatible with the latest version of EKS.

```
import boto3
from packaging import version

eks = boto3.client('eks', region_name='eu-west-2')

response = eks.describe_addon_versions()
eks_versions = []

for addon in response['addons']:
    for addonVersion in addon['addonVersions']:
        for compatibility in addonVersion['compatibilities']:
            eks_versions.append(compatibility['clusterVersion'])

eks_versions = list(set(eks_versions))

for n, i in enumerate(eks_versions):
    eks_versions[n] = version.parse(i)

latest_eks_version = max(eks_versions)

print(latest_eks_version)
```